# Can you get the behaviour of this function when $\rho\to0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following function
$$
v(\rho)=-\frac{\pi}{\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho}\int_0^{\infty}dx\,e^{-x}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi/2}{\log\left(\frac{\rho}{x}\right)}\right)
$$
where we have that $\rho>0$. I am interested in the $\rho\to0$ behaviour $v$. The paper I am reading (https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0303120v3.pdf the equations (7) and (8) ) says that this small $\rho$ behaviour is given by
$$
v(\rho)\sim-\frac{\pi}{2\rho\log(1/\rho)}\qquad\rho\to0
$$
Almost in the end of section 3 the author states that this asymptotic form can be obtained "expanding the integrand around $\log x$". I don't really see how this is supposed to be a help. So, can anybody get the quoted asymptotic form?

Comment: The idea is to use the fact that $\arctan y \sim y$ as $y \to 0$ to replace $\arctan\frac{\pi/2}{\log\frac{\rho}{x}}$ by $\frac{\pi/2}{\log\frac{\rho}{x}}$ or, more simply, just $\frac{\pi/2}{\log\rho}$, in the integral.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I understand how you ignore the arctan but why can you drop the $x$?

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus $-\ln\left(\rho\right) \gg \ln\left(x\right)$

Comment: @AntonioVargas How do you justify pushing the limit (of $\rho \to 0$) under the integral?

Comment: @angryavian I was only giving direction. The justification is indeed the tricky part.

Comment: Actually, looking at the expression more closely, I take issue with the paper's claim. The integral term is indeed asymptotic to $\pi/(2\rho\log\rho)$ but the $-\pi/\rho$ term is dominant. The correct asymptotic is $v(\rho) \sim -\pi/\rho$ as $\rho \to 0$, which is supported by numerics.

Comment: Weird that you have integrand after $dx.$

Comment: The integral $\to 0$ simply from the dominated convergence theorem.